# CloudBlobClient .setTimeoutInMs() do not work

Tags: android, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to set time out value for:

```
CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClientUserData = cloudClientAccountUserData.createCloudBlobClient();
cloudBlobClientUserData.setTimeoutInMs(60000); //1 Minute 

CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClientUserData.getContainerReference(containerName);
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobName);

inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
blob.upload(inputStream, data.length);
```

Sometime when weak internet connection is available `blob.upload(....)` does not time out after 1 minute. it takes more than 10 minutes.

Any idea why this is happening like this?

PS: I have tried even 1 milisecond e.g:

```
cloudBlobClientUserData.setTimeoutInMs(1);
```

but still every blob is being uploaded on Azure cloud. no time out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the documentation of this functionality [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-api/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/core/storage/ServiceClient.java) and one thing caught my eye is the last statement below:

> The server timeout interval begins at the time that the complete
>   request has been received by the service, and the server begins
>   processing the response. If the timeout interval elapses before the
>   response is returned to the client, the operation times out. **The
>   timeout interval resets with each retry, if the request is retried**.

Here's what I'm thinking is happening:

I'm assuming that you're not explicitly setting retry policies and thus the storage client library uses default retry policy (which is exponential retry policy). So your first request gets timed out and the request is retried however when the request is retried, the timeout interval is reset to it's default value which is 90 seconds. Can you try by explicitly setting retry policy to `No Retry` so that the request is not retried and see if your requests are getting timed out based on the interval you specify in your code.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense. In Windows sdk they have CloudBlobClient.RetryPolicy property BUT in Android i could not find any method to set Retry Policy on my own. Any help how I can set Retry policy with java code in Android?

Comment: There's a function called setRetryPolicyFactory in ServiceClient class. More details here: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-api/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/core/storage/ServiceClient.java. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout setting applies to a single storage service operation.  I'm not sure how big your blob is, but I suspect it is being uploaded in smaller chunks.  Each chunk that is uploaded is subject to the timeout.  So, while the entire upload may be taking several minutes, each chunk is getting completed within the timeout period.

Another possibility is that there are retries occurring.  If there is a retry, then the timeout get's reset.  So, there could be some intermittent failures occurring that are resolved in a retry attempt.

You can verify all this using Fiddler to trace the upload. For example, look for lines like this in the trace:

PUT https://.blob.core.windows.net/test/?comp=block&blockid=MkZGREU3RkItMDAwMDE1&timeout=90 HTTP/1.

Answer (score 0):

I am not super familiar with the Android stuff, but can you trace the request?  You should see the REST call on the wire and it will have a '&timeout=xxx' parameter if it is getting set.  Usually this is per block and not per blob.  What is your retry policy?  Make sure you turn that off as well.